cannot install PyQt6 on python 32 bits
I developed an application with PyQt6 with a 64-bit version of Python. I even generated the setup but this setup does not work on a 32-bit machine. According to the documentation I installed 32-bit python to be able to obtain an executable that works on 32-bit Windows. But PyQt6 does not install.Below is what the console returns to me
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "E:\nassProject32\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "E:\nassProject32\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "E:\nassProject32\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-56x2672a\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 28, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-56x2672a\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 74, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-56x2672a\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 602, in setup
          self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-95onda65\pyqt6_70b0094829bb439594cf910c3649ee20\project.py", line 66, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-56x2672a\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 51, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-56x2672a\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 237, in apply_user_defaults
          self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-56x2672a\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 50, in apply_user_defaults
          raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
      sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException

Note that I tried python version 3.9 3.10 3.11 3.12
Comment resoudre ce probleme ?

See the documentation: Qt6 does not support 32-bit architecture anymore. If you want to support 32-bit on your program, then either you build Qt and PyQt on your own (highly discouraged unless you're experienced enough), or use Qt5.
